# Clique no icone da action bar para abrir uma nova intent

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber como faço para clicar no icone/palavra na action bar e este abrir uma nova intent.

Estou fazendo o seguinte:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.marcas:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Item 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            break;
        }

    return true;
}
```

Ele me retorna a mensagem de como cliquei no icone, mas gostaria de abrir uma nova intent.

Comment: é só você chamar a intent no lugar do toast

Comment: @Joannis, fiz e não deu certo cara. Já tinha tentado isso. Podes colocar o código de como você fez ?

Comment: postei, ve se funciona!

Comment: @Joannis, fiz como você me mostrou ai. Deu um erro:

Error:(98, 2) error: reached end of file while parsing

Já fechei todas as chaves

Comment: tenta agora, faltou o return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.menueditar) {

            Intent iedicao = new Intent(MainActivity.this, paginadeedicao.class);

            startActivity(iedicao);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

onde:

```
                Intent iedicao = new Intent(MainActivity.this, paginadeedicao.class);
```

Você cria um intent novo com o nome nesse caso de iedicao que vai da mainActivity (atividade atual) para paginadeedicao.class (que é uma outra página do código)

Você também pode enviar parâmetros com o put extra:

```
    iedicao.putExtra("pagina", page);
```

tem que vir antes do startActivity.

Você ta inflando o menu?

```
//coloca os ícones no menu
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        if(featureId == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR && menu != null){
            if(menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")){
                try{
                    Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    m.invoke(menu, true);
                } catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
                } catch(Exception e){
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }

        return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
    }
    //cria todos os menus
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        onMenuOpened(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR, menu);
        return true;
    }
    //seta as opções de função dos itens do menu
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.menueditar) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, edicao.class));
            MainActivity.this.finish();

            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

isso

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, edicao.class));
```

é igual a isso

```
Intent iedicao = new Intent(MainActivity.this, paginadeedicao.class);

startActivity(iedicao);
```

Comment: Consegui cara. Fiz o que você disse, só troquei alguns pontos. 
Ajudou bastante.
Muito obrigado.

Comment: coloca como correta a resposta, hahah a gente se ajuda, assim o mundo cresce